# Javascript XMLHttpRequest result will not store in a variable for other use

Tags: php, javascript, function, variables, global-variables

I'm submitting a form but need my form to run some checks first so i'm calling in some javascript which needs to run an XMLHttpRequest to see if something is set on another PHP script. I can get the value back but only output the message within the area where i am getting the response, any attempt of putting this into a variable and using elsewhere doesn't work, here's my script:

```
function validateform() {

var complete = "Please fill in the following fields:";
var temp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {

    temp=xmlhttp.responseText;
     alert(temp);
    }
  }


xmlhttp.open("GET","hrp/recaptcha/verify.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();

alert(temp);
```

The first "alert(temp") gets outputted but then the one after at the end of the code always says undefined so I cant use it outside.

Any ideas?
Thanks :D

Comment: AJAX runs asynchronously, you need to wait for the value to come back. The second alert runs immediately and there is no value yet, the first runs with the callback which is run when the data has actually been received.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense, how would I make it wait for the response without running the other code first?

Comment: you could use a promise - I found quite a few StackOverflow answers about using promises with XMLhttpRequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you don't want an asynchronous call, in which case you'll want to do:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","hrp/recaptcha/verify.php",false);
```

You can also remove the block:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
```

Comment: NOTE: Running a request synchronously will make the page freeze until the result is returned.

Comment: @TheZ Yep. Make sure this is what you want before making any code edits. The asychronous aspect of Ajax is what allows applications to load pages in parts rather than a whole page load... but also prevents you from gracefully using return values.

Comment: It is a little jarring to have the browser lock up, and there are ways of making the AJAX work as long as you abide by the logic of it.